# How to run a task automatically when a gradle script is called

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a file that needs to be pushed into a specific directory when the project is built with gradle.
My solution so far is inside the build.gradle itself:

```
....
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
from 'filename'
into 'dirctoryname'
}
```

The other question on this website wonder, why their tasks are being executed automatically and are told that they need to add a closure inside the task (like doLast).

I however actually want the task to be executed automatically, so I am not using any closures.
When I run the task manually it works just fine and the file gets copied into the directory.

When I however rightclick -> run the build script in IntelliJ nothing happens.
How can I let the task get executed automatically any time the build script is executed?

I was thinking of something like "dependsOn this" but that just throws nasty errors.
And "build.dependsOn copyTask" doesn't throw errors, but also doesn't copy the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link the creation of `filename` also into the deps.  E.g.

```
copyTask.dependsOn myBuildStep
assemle.dependsOn copyTask
```